# If you randomly call $5$ students and each call is independent, what is the probability that no student is called twice?

Tags: probability

I am thinking about this question and I don't really know how to tackle it.

The problem is:

> The class has $30$ students. If you want to call 5 students, each one is independent of the others and randomly with equal probability, what is the probability that none are repeated?

I am thinking as $$\frac{30\cdot 29\cdot 28 \cdot  27\cdot 26}{30^5},$$ but I am not sure it is correct. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think this is kinda similar to the Birthday problem ...

Comment: ... the downvoter may want to explain, it is really a bad idea to downvote a first (acceptable) question of a new contributor in the first minutes without comment.

Comment: I just want to check my intuition is correct. I am so sorry that it is similar to the birthday problem.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it as a bowl with 30 blue marbles (all the students). Whenever a student is called, we replace a blue marble with a red marble (so this is a student we have already called). Now what is the probability that we don't grab a red marble after 5 times?

So the first attempt, P(blue) is obviously one.
The second attempt, we have P(blue) = $\frac{29}{30}$.
The third, fourth and fifth attempt, we have respectively:

$\frac{28}{30}$, $\frac{27}{30}$, $\frac{26}{30}$

Multiplying these

$1 \times \frac{29}{30} \times \frac{28}{30} \times \frac{27}{30} \times \frac{26}{30}$

we get $\approx$ $70.4$%...

The same will be:

$(\frac{1}{30})^5 \times (30 \times 29 \times 28 \times 27 \times 26) $

So yes, your answer is correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct.

$30 \cdot 29 \cdot 28 \cdot 27 \cdot 26$ or $^{30}P_5$ is the number of ways to permute $5$ students out of $30$ without repetition. $30^5$ is the total number of ways, so the probability is:

$$\frac{30 \cdot 29 \cdot 28 \cdot 27 \cdot 26}{30^5} \approx 0.704.$$